# boton dentro de un td no funciona Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buen dia

Etoy tratando de hacer una accion al momento de hacer click en un boton que esta dentro de un 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estos son dos  de mi tabla (modifique la imagen para no mostrar los datos de la tabla). del lado derecho podemos ver los dos botones que quiero que realicen una accion

Inicialmente en mi html solo tengo

```
<table class="table">
    <tbody id="tableRequest">

    </tbody>
</table>
```

posteriormente hago una peticion con ajax para obtener los datos de mi tabla y en el success de mi ajax lleno la tabla de la siguiente manera

```
success: function (data) {
  data.forEach(function (item, index) {
      $('#tableRequest').append(
'<tr>'
+ '<td>' + item.data.request.idRequest + '</td>'
+ '<td>' + item.data.request.wiw + '</td>'
+ '<td>' + item.name + '</td>'
+ '<td>' + item.data.ousu.OUSUDescription + '</td>'
+ '<td>' + item.data.pool.poolDescription + '</td>'
+ '<td>' + item.data.role.roleDescription + '</td>'
+ '<td>' + item.data.request.comments + '</td>'
+ ' <td class="td-actions text-right">'
+ '<button rel="tooltip" title="Aceptar" class="aceptar btn btn-success btn-link btn-sm boton">'
+ 'palomita'
+ '</button>'
+ '<button type="button" rel="tooltip" title="Negar" class="negar btn btn-danger btn-link btn-sm boton">'
+ '<i class="negar material-icons">close</i>'
+ '</button>'
+ '</td>'
+ '</tr>'
)
```

he intentado ejecutar la accion de diferentes maneras pero ninguna me funciona. Estas son algunas de las formas en las que lo he intentado

```
$('.aceptar').click(function(){
     alert('hacer accion')
});

$('#tableRequest tbody').on('click', '.aceptar', function () {
    alert('hacer accion')
});
```

lo e intentado con la clase aceptar en el boton asi como con la clase aceptar en el elemento

¿Alguna idea del porque no funciona?

Comment: Cuantas veces mandas llamar a ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La primera de las maneras no te funciona porque al `.aceptar` ser un elemento que se crea dinamicamente, cuando se le trata de vincular la función `click` este no se encuentra todavía en el **DOM** por lo que no es capaz de hacerlo.

En su lugar haría algo como:

```
$(document).on('click', '.aceptar', function() {
  alert('hacer accion');
});
```

De esta manera el evento se lo estás dando al `document`, que si que se encuentra presente en el momento de cargarse el **DOM** por lo que el evento quedaría bien vinculado.

La segunda forma que has intentado no te funciona porque dentro de tu **HTML** no existe ningún elemento `tbody` que tenga como **ancestro** un elemento `#tableRequest`. El espacio entre elementos dentro de un selector indica un cambio de nivel de parentesco. Si lo que quieres es hacer referencia a un elemento que sea tanto un `<tbody>` como `#tableRequest` debes quitar el espacio entre ellos:

```
$('tbody#tableRequest').on('click', '.aceptar', function () {
    alert('hacer accion')
});
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias amigo! Ya tenia un buen rato intentando solucionar este problema te lo agradezco mucho